# Add to Nuxt.js application analytics script, which execution depends on current url

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, nuxt.js, yandex-metrika

I have Nuxt.js application which is using 'universal' mode.

My task is to insert Yandex-metrika(similar to Google analytics) into my Nuxt.js application.

I have three problems:

1. script should be used on every page
2. script should be used only in production environment
3. script should be used only on specific domain, for example: `domain.com`

I tried to use app.html to include my script.
First two problems are solved with below solution, but last one remains: how to know current url?
I have no access to `window` from Nuxt.js template syntax, `window.location.host` would have solve my problem easily.

*app.html*

```
{% if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { %}
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
<script type="text/javascript" >
  // script execution
</script>

<noscript>
  <div>
    <img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/00000000" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" />
  </div>
</noscript>
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
{% } %}
```

I can add condition statement to my `<script>`, like
`if (window.location.host === 'domain.com')`
but what to do with `<noscript>` then? How to conditionally hide it?

I also considered to putting alalytics script into plugin, but this solution has side problems - analytics does not work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the option **Receive data only from specified adresses** to prevent sending extraneous data to your reports from unneeded domains.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

3- You should not worry about the `noscript` tag, it's only a fallback when javascript is disabled on your browser.

> The [noscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) HTML element defines a section of HTML to be
> inserted if a script type on the page is unsupported or if scripting
> is currently turned off in the browser.

1- As you said for this problem you can use different approaches like `plugins`, `app.html` (with window.location.host and check for correct domain), etc.

2- for the second problem you can use the `.env` file and set different values for different environments(production, staging, etc), and use `procss.env.GA_ID`, in the `nuxt.config.js` file, inside [`head`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-head) property you can load scripts conditionally.

.env file

> ```
> GA_ID=UA-17XXXX23-X
> ```

```
// example with analytics
// nuxt.config.js
// inside export default
head: {
   script: [
      {
         src: 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=' + process.env.GA_ID
      },
      {
         src: '/gtm.js'
      }
   ],
}
```